# Удалить script из кода страницы на php

Tags: php

Как удалить теги скриптов со страницы на php
использую эту регулярку

```
#<script[^>]*>.*?</script>#is
```

но она не справляется с таким:

```
<script>КОД</script> нужный мне текст <script>Снова КОД</script>
```

она удаляет весь текст от первого до последнего script, удаляя также *нужный мне текст*

как быть?

Comment: Запустил вашу регулярку на [regexpr.ru](http://regexpr.ru/) - отработало нормально, нашло два совпадения "КОД" и "СНОВА КОД".

Запустил у себя - вырезало нормально.

Покажите как вы вырезаете текст.

Comment: [pre]$page = preg_replace('#<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>#is','', $page);[/pre]

Comment: Делаю так:

    $string = '<script>КОД</script> нужный мне текст <script>Снова КОД</script>';
    $pattern = '#<script[^>]*>.*?</script>#is';
    $replacement = '';
    $string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
    echo $string;

На выводе получаю ' нужный мне текст ' - что я делаю не так?

Может быть не справляется не с вашим пример, а с чем-то типа:

    <script>КОД</script><script src=""/> нужный мне текст <script>Снова КОД</script>

Comment: @BOPOH задай знечение переменной `$string = file_get_contents('http://hashcode.ru/');` и посмотри справится ли регулярка?!

Comment: Всем спасибо все работает! Ошибка была в том что сервер отдавал там ссылок не было - а я весь переочковал.

Comment: @Palmervan, я не утверждаю, что регулярка со всем справится.

У ТС возникли трудности на конкретной регулярке с конкретным примером. Я по этому примеру и писал.

И привел свой пример, который ломает указанную регулярку. Так что...

UPD: попробовал, вроде получилось)) Если битые ссылки и стили не считать))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с версии php 3.0.9, появилась новая функция `preg_match_all`, может она пригодится в этом случае :)

Так же полезно прочесть о переносах строк при использовании в регулярных выражениях!